# C Structures: Initialized Strings become invalid

Tags: c, struct

I have the following code example which gets a pointer to a structure in two different ways. While the first one ("Test1") succeeds, the second one fails with a Segmentation fault when trying to output the string (*title*), while the number (*type*) is printed properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    unsigned char type;
    char* title;
} MenuItem;

typedef struct{
    unsigned short itemCount;
    MenuItem *items;    
} Menu;

Menu* createMenu(unsigned short itemCount, MenuItem items[]){
    Menu *menu = malloc(sizeof(Menu));
    menu->itemCount = itemCount;
    menu->items = items;
    return menu;
}

Menu* getSampleMenu(void){
    return createMenu(2,(MenuItem[]){
        {3,"Foo2"},
        {4,"Bar2"}
    });
}

void showMenu(const Menu *menu){
    for(unsigned short i = 0; i < menu->itemCount; i++)
        printf("Item %d: %d/%s\n",i,menu->items[i].type,menu->items[i].title);
}

int main(void){
    //Test 1
    Menu *menu = createMenu(2,(MenuItem[]){
        {1,"Foo"},
        {2,"Bar"}
    });
    showMenu(menu);
    //Result: 1/Foo\n 2/Bar

    //Test 2
    showMenu(getSampleMenu());
    //Result: 3/ [segmentation fault]
}
```

Do you have any idea what the problem might be? The example is compiled and tested on Debian using gcc 4.6.3 in C99 mode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The array you're passing to `createMenu` has "automatic storage duration".  It dies, and any pointers to it become invalid, once `getSampleMenu` ends.

(Edit: It might actually be even more severe than that.  The array, being a temporary object, may well be dead once *the statement that caused its creation* ends.  In this case the two are about equivalent, since that statement is the last one in the function...but were there subsequent statements in `createSampleMenu` that attempted to use that menu, even they may be following invalid pointers.)

You'll need to dynamically allocate (`malloc`) some memory and copy the array into it.  (Of course, then you should also have a `destroyMenu` or similar function to properly free the memory once the menu's no longer needed.)

Answer (score 2):

Variables that are declared locally, also called "[automatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)", are usually stored on the stack frame of the current function - so that when you return from the function in which they were declared, they are popped from the stack, and a function called later could write over them. `malloc` allocates a range of memory on the heap, which remains allocated to your use until you call `free`, regardless of the scope your code is in.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer `menu->items` is lo longer valid once the function `getSampleMenu()` returns because "MenuItem[]" is locally defined in this function.

So in test 2, your program segfault when accessing `menu->items` in `showMenu()`.